# change the state of the child component

Tags: reactjs

I am having a Parent Component and a child component

```
export default class CityPart extends Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            citylist: citylist
            selectedflag:1
        }

    }
    Clickme(idd){
     this.setstate({selectedflag:idd})
}
    render() {
        return (
        <div className="CityPartMain">
            {this.state.citylist.map((item)=>{
                return (
                <EachCity name ={item.name} key={item.id}
                id={item.id}
                selected={this.state.selected}
                Clickme ={this.Clickme}
                />
                )
            })}
        </div>
        );

    }
}
```

```
export default class EachCity extends Component { 
    render() {
        const {name,id,selected,Clickme} = this.props;    
        return (
            <button 
            onClick={this.Clickme(id)}
            className={selected===parseInt(id,10)?"selectedcity": "EachCityMain"}>
            <p>{name}</p>
            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

whenever i click on the button i want that id should come to my parent component and it should get updated in the selectedflag of the parent state.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made two mistakes.
First one is in your parent - this is how you should implement method `Clickme`:

```
Clickme = (id) => {
    this.setState({selectedflag:idd})
}
```

In your implementation `this` means object, which is calling method (child), so `this.setState()` will work for child.
When you use lambda expression - it will work for parent.

Second mistake is how are you calling `Clickme` in your child component.
You should make it like:

```
<button 
    onClick={() => Clickme(id)}
    className={selected === parseInt(id,10) ? "selectedcity" : "EachCityMain"}
    >
        <p>{name}</p>
</button>
```

If you are calling function without parameters, you can just pass function to `onClick`. In your case you have to create anonymous function to call it with parameter. Additionaly `this` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Clickme` callback is getting called right away (remember, function() is called right then) and you are just storing the result of that call in the `onClick` handler. You're also using `this`. Try instead setting it as a callback using an anonymous arrow function.

```
export default class EachCity extends Component { 
  render() {
    const { name, id, selected, Clickme} = this.props;    
    return (
      <button 
        onClick={() => Clickme(id)}
        className={selected===parseInt(id,10) ? "selectedcity" : "EachCityMain"}
      >
        <p>{name}</p>
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

If this is unclear to you and how and why it works, I can add a codesandbox example with more detail.

Comment: ``` i needed to convert the selected value to int. now it works``` thanks